# Is there any formula for the following?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any formula for the following?

Given fixed integer $m \in [n-2]$, what is the number of n-permutations 
$p=p_1p_2 \cdots p_n $ with $|p_k - p_{k-1}| \ge m$ for all $k=1, 2, \cdots, n $?
Here we let $p_0 :=p_n$.

If there is, say, let $f(n,m)$ be such a number. What is its generating function?
Of course, the case $m=1$ is obvious. Probably we need PIE for the case $m=2$.